# Given that $F(x)=\int^x_0e^{t^2}dt+1$, which of these is true?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Let $F(x)=\int^x_0e^{t^2}dt+1$. Then: 

a) $F(x)$ is convex in $(-\infty , \infty )$. 
b) The equation $F(x)=0$ has two solutions. 
c) $F(x)$ is invertible and $(F^{-1})'(1)=1$. 
d) $F(1)=5$. 
e) $F(x)=F(-x)$ for every $x$.

---

**My attempt:**

a) $F'(x)=e^{x^2}$, $F''(x)=2xe^{x^2}<0$ for $x<0$ so it's not true. 
b) I don't know how to disprove this one. 
c) I know that $(F^{-1})'(F(x))=\frac {1}{F'(x)}$, I hesitated a lot here, since if I want to get $(F^{-1})'(1)$, I need to substitute $x=0$, but do I substitute also $x=0$ in $F'(x)$ or $x=1$? (this was  critical to know for this question). 
d) I got no idea just pure intuition that the area at $x=1$ of $e^{x^2}$ would be less than $5$. 
e) That's not true, it changes the integral, and will somewhere affect the $e$ being with $(-)$ in the solution.

The answer was c). I would really appreciate any help in disproving the wrong answers and any tips regarding my confusion about c).

Comment: how does $F(0)=0$? Could you explain? I think it should be $F(0)=1$

Comment: @FrankMoses Welp I even missed that, that's a mistake with calculation I'll edit it that I don't know how to disprove it, thanks.

Comment: I am unable to see even a single value of $x$ for which the function will be zero

Comment: Do you mean $(F^{-1})'(1) = 1$ in (c)? Otherwise it is wrong.

Comment: For d), note that $\exp x^2$ is increasing so $F(1)=1+\int_0^1\exp x^2\,dx<1+e<5$.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, my bad, edited it now.

Comment: For b), note that $F(x)$ is strictly increasing as $F'(x)=\exp x^2>0$ so $F$ cannot have two zeros.

Comment: This also implies that $F$ is invertible as it is continuous and its range is the set of real numbers. Now $(F^{-1})'(1)=[F'(F^{-1}(1))]^{-1}=F'(0)^{-1}$ as $F$ is bijective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(b) is wrong because $F'(x) = e^{x^2} > 0$, so that $F$ is strictly increasing.

For (c) one can use that $F'(x) = e^{x^2} \ge 1$ implies that the range of $F$ is $\Bbb R$ and $F$ is invertible. Then
$$
 (F^{-1})'(1) = \frac{1}{F'(F^{-1}(1))}=  \frac{1}{F'(0)} = \frac{1}{e^{0^2}} = 1 \, .
$$

Comment: Thanks alot, for (c), I never remember the formula for some reason and this time I started it $F^{-1}(F(x))=x$, and took derivative and got $F'(x)=[(F^{-1})'(F(x))]^{-1}$, knowing that $F(0)=1$, and $F'(0)=1$, would this be a validate solution also?

Comment: @Pwaol: Yes, that is the same formula, only for the inverse function.

Answer (score 1):

The key to quickly answer these multiple choice questions is to identify the largest commonality, which in this case is the sign of the first derivative.

The fact that $F'(x)=e^{x^2}$ means $F$ is strictly increasing. This immediately eliminates

- **b)** as $F$ crosses the horizontal axis at most once;
- **e)** as no even function is strictly increasing on the entire domain, and
- **d)** as $\int_0^1e^{t^2}\,dt<(1-0)\times e^{1^2}$.

We can eliminate **a)** by differentiating again to check the sign, which you have correctly done.

With **c)**, we know that $F$ is invertible as it is continuous and its range is the set of real numbers. The inverse derivative formula which is derived from using the chain rule on $F^{-1}(F(x))=x$, can be used to evaluate $(F^{-1})'(1)=[F'(F^{-1}(1))]^{-1}=F'(0)^{-1}$ as $F$ is bijective.

Thus **c)** is the only correct answer.